# Does PDAL operate on pgPointcloud PcPatch objects? (Trying to figure out how/if PDAL, PCL, Entwine, PostgreSQL fit together.)

Tags: mapping, database, pdal, pgpointcloud, pcl

I'm starting from nothing; I have large amounts of lidar scan points and image data that I need to process and store and create deliverables from.
I've never used PDAL, PCL, GDAL, PostgreSQL or Entwine; though it seems they could be used together to build an application.  I want to write an application in either C++ or Rust, to process the lidar and image data I have.
I have a number of general questions:

- Is Entwine a database similar to PostgreSQL?  Can I install Entwine locally?  Or, what are my options for storing scan and image data?  I need to temporarily store and search on large amounts of scan point and image data while it is being processed, and also store results of the processing for later retrieval.
- The concept of a PcPatch object in pgPointcloud might be useful for my workflow. But I will need to write my own 'chipper' that will bin scan points in a particular way.  Is writing a custom chipper possible?  And once I have the PcPatch objects I need, can other libraries such as PDAL operate on the PcPatch objects in-place in a database?
- A motivation for using PcPatch in pgPointcloud is that I will need to search on the PcPatch objects and return those having specific properties.
- In case I do use pgPointclould, is it possible to constuct a custom data object composed of multiple specific PcPatch(es) and other data objects such as vectors and matrices?
- It seems that PCL, PDAL and GDAL contain functionality I need but it's unclear to me how to use these libraries together and what database should be used to store the intermediate and final processing results.
- Coordinate transformations and mapping (re)projections are also required in this work.

So I have a lot of general questions.  I'm hoping the answers I get back will help me to formulate a sensible (and scalable) workflow that I can implement using some of these software libraries.  Which other software packages might I consider?